# Conda not recognized as internal or external after creating new environment

Tags: python, anaconda

**conda** command was working fine from **Anaconda** prompt. I created a new environment for `tensorflow` after which it says - `'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

I have checked all my **PATH** variables, and root, scripts and lib folder paths are added to the **PATH**.

It just does not recognize any commands - conda, activate, deactivate, any of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. **PATH**s were also fine but I was unable to execute the **conda** command.

While installing **Anaconda**, I had checked **ADD TO PATH** option, I think that created problem.

**Anaconda** does not recommend to do this. You can see **RED** colored warning if you check the **ADD TO PATH** check box.

See the below 2 images.

**Before checking the box**

[image]

**After checking the box**

[image]

Finally I reinstalled the **Anaconda**  without checking the check box **ADD TO PATH** then manually set the **PATH**.

Better is to use your own custom location for **Anaconda** installation as I did.

I do not know, in which system you are working. I am windows user and solved the issue as follows.

1. Uninstalled the currently installed **Anaconda**.
2. Created folder named `C:\AnacondaPython`  for reinstallation of **Anaconda**.
3. Manually added the following 5 **PATHS** to **PATH** environment variable.

   C:\AnacondaPython

   C:\AnacondaPython\Scripts

   C:\AnacondaPython\Library

   C:\AnacondaPython\Library\mingw-w64\bin

   C:\AnacondaPython\Library\usr\bin

**Or** you can just append the below **PATH** series.

```
C:\AnacondaPython;C:\AnacondaPython\Scripts;C:\AnacondaPython\Library;C:\AnacondaPython\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\AnacondaPython\Library\usr\bin
```

So finally, I opened new **Terminal**, and tried to create, activate & deactivate `tensorflow` environment.

Please check my `Terminal`s history that is given below.

```
(base) C:\Users\sunil kumar>conda create --name tensorflow
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.4.10
  latest version: 4.4.11

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda


## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\AnacondaPython\envs\tensorflow


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate tensorflow
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate


(base) C:\Users\Rishikesh>conda activate tensorflow

(tensorflow) C:\Users\Rishikesh>conda deactivate

(base) C:\Users\Rishikesh>
```

I will suggest you reinstall your **Anaconda** to get rid of this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: In my case (Windows) adding "C:\Users\<user name>\[Miniconda3 | Anaconda3]\Scripts" was enough to solve the problem without reinstallation (see https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/8KUBC81_t_k)

Comment: Yeah, actually that is sufficient to start. Actually, what I have mentioned in my answer is a result of a research work. Anaconda installer sets all the above entries if you check **Add to PATH** option but that causes problems later (so manual PATH setting is better). So once you will move any development where Anaconda/Miniconda really needs any of these, in that case you may face issues. But most of the suggestions will still suggest to set the path to **Scripts** and **Anaconda HOME**.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me as well. I created a new env and was able to switch to the new env using command conda activate . But once I was in the new env I was not able to use conda command at all, even to deactivate the env.

I just opened a new WIN's command prompt then switched to the new env and then was able to use conda command with no issues.