# How to use python using anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) for python 3.7 in my windows 10 pc.

When I put `python` in `gitBash`, it says

`bash: python: command not found`

How can I use python globally? So I can use python command everywhere.

Comment: Did you check `Add to PATH` option while installing it? If not then you will need to manually add the PATH.

Comment: I can not remember. Can I check it somehow now?

Comment: Check my  answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142567/conda-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-after-creating-new-environment/49346022#49346022 and set PATH then try again, check my answer as well for few more steps. I have added picture for Windows 10, it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should execute "Anaconda Prompt" and then you can start "python" from there.

it is not recommended to "add to path" during Anaconda installation on Windows 10. So, it's normal python from Anaconda is not in your path.

Comment: Now I can use python from `Anaconda Prompt`. But how can I use it in `gitBash` or vs code integrated terminal? Is it a bad practice?

Comment: @ShamsNahid you can check https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: by default, you have "base" already and you can create new virtualenv too.

Comment: I usually use pyCharm but I just have had a quick check on VS code on my Mac and windows 10, it works as expected. please let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Add python to your path like this:

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/path/to/python
```

and do not specify the .exe then you can use it from git bash

Answer (score 0):

@Nahid, you can check my answer at [Conda not recognized as internal or external after creating new environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142567/conda-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-after-creating-new-environment/49346022#49346022).

- Close already opened terminals.
- Follow the instructions given in that link.
- Open new terminal (Git BASH).
- Type `winpty python` or `python -i` (Simply typing `python` on terminal will not work).

Enjoy and ask/comment here if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you installed Anaconda. Unless you have install Linux version of Anaconda(preferable Miniconda), you need to point gitBash to your Windows Python. E.g. in gitBash

```
alias python='winpty python.exe'
```

If you want a specific Python the 'winpty fullpath/python.exe' to make it permanent, add that command to your .bashrc

```
cd ~
touch .bashrc
```

Then add the command above. Save and restart your terminal.

Similar issue: [Python not working in the command line of git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash)